# How can I add each students ca and exam score in different input Fields and display their total in separate text field

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm new in jQuery. I want the user to enter the CAT score and the EXAM score to get Total score, Grade, Remark and Position. The result to be displayed should be dependent on the addition of both CAT and EXAM score. Like once the user is enters the cat score and the exam score, the script should be able to add both, then display the total, the grade which could be A, B, ..., Remark and the position of the student based on the already entered scores.
Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
$sql=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * from students where class='$classId'");
echo '
<div  class="adv-table padTable">
          <table id="marks"  class="table table-bordered" id="hidden-table-info">
            <caption><h3 style="text-align: center;">RESULT SHEET</h3></caption>
             <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>SN</th>
                <th width="40%">Student Name</th>
                <th>CAT</th>
                <th>Exam Score</th>
                <th>Total Score</th>
                <th>Grade</th>
                <th>Remark</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                
              </tr>
            </thead>

<tbody>';

$sn=0;
while ($res=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo  '<form action="'. htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).' " method="post" class="style-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <tr>
    <td>'.++$sn.'<input type="text" value="'.$res['id'].'" hidden="" name="studId"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-inline input-medium " value="'.$res['surname'].'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'. $res['othernames'].'" readonly=""></td>
    <td> 
      <div class="form-group">
    
        <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-inline input-medium cat" id="cat" name="cat" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode==0)? null: event.charCode >=48 && event.charCode <=57">
        </td>
        
        <td>
        <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-inline input-medium examScore" id="examScore" name="examScore"  onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode==0)? null: event.charCode >=48 && event.charCode <=57" >
        </td>
        
         <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-inline input-medium totScore" id="totScore" name="totScore"  readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-inline input-medium grade" id="grade" name="grade"  readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-inline input-medium remark" id="remark" name="remark"  readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
     <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-inline input-medium position" id="position" name="position" readonly=""  >
     
            </td>     
              </div>
          </div>

    
    </tr>
    </form>' ;
```

**JQUERY CODE**

```
$('#marks').on('input', '.cat', '.examScore', function() {
    var examScore = (".examScore").val();
    $mark = $(this)
    var cat = $mark.val();
    total
    field
    $row = $mark.closest('tr')
    $studTotalScore = $row.find('.totScore')
    studTotalScore = parseInt(cat) + parseInt(examScore);

    $studTotalScore.val(studTotalScore).attr('readonly', true);

    $studTotalScore.val(studTotalScore).attr('readonly', true);
    $studentgrade = $row.find('.grade')
    $remarks = $row.find('.remark')
    if (studTotalScore >= 90 && studTotalScore <= 100) {
        calculatedgrade = "A";
        remark = "Excellent";
    }

    $studentgrade.val(calculatedgrade).attr('readonly', true);

    $remarks.val(remark).attr('readonly', true);
});
```

Comment: Your PHP code is vulnerable to a critical SQL injection vulnerability - you *really* should use prepared statements and parameterized queries to mitigate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector syntax is wrong it should be `'.cat , .examScore'` if you need to use multiple classes in same event. Then , you can check if the `cat` or `examscore` values are not empty depending on this get value typed by user or take `0` then set your values in your required inputs.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//use comma 
$('#marks').on('input', '.cat , .examScore', function() {
  var $mark = $(this)
  $row = $mark.closest('tr')
  //check if the value is not "" else use 0
  var examScore = $row.find('.examScore').val() != "" ? $row.find('.examScore').val() : 0;
  var cat = $row.find('.cat').val() != "" ? $row.find('.cat').val() : 0;
  //declare variables
  var $studTotalScore = $row.find('.totScore')
  studTotalScore = parseInt(cat) + parseInt(examScore);
  $studTotalScore.val(studTotalScore).attr('readonly', true);
  var $studentgrade = $row.find('.grade')
  var $remarks = $row.find('.remark')
  var calculatedgrade, remark;
  if (studTotalScore >= 90 &&
    studTotalScore <= 100) {
    calculatedgrade = "A";
    remark = "Excellent";
  }
  $studentgrade.val(calculatedgrade).attr('readonly', true);
  $remarks.val(remark).attr('readonly', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="adv-table padTable">
  <table id="marks" class="table table-bordered" id="hidden-table-info">
    <caption>
      <h3 style="text-align: center;">RESULT SHEET</h3>
    </caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>SN</th>
        <th width="40%">Student Name</th>
        <th>CAT</th>
        <th>Exam Score</th>
        <th>Total Score</th>
        <th>Grade</th>
        <th>Remark</th>
        <th>Position</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <form action="'. htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).' " method="post" class="style-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <tr>
          <td>1<input type="text" value="1" hidden="" name="studId"></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-inline input-medium " value="s s" readonly=""></td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">

              <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-inline input-medium cat" id="cat" name="cat">
          </td>

          <td>
            <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-inline input-medium examScore" name="examScore">
          </td>

          <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-inline input-medium totScore" id="totScore" name="totScore" readonly="">
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-inline input-medium grade" name="grade" readonly="">
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-inline input-medium remark" name="remark" readonly="">
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-inline input-medium position" name="position" readonly="">

          </td>


        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1<input type="text" value="2" hidden="" name="studId"></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-inline input-medium " value="ss ss" readonly=""></td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">

              <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-inline input-medium cat" name="cat">
          </td>

          <td>
            <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-inline input-medium examScore" name="examScore">
          </td>

          <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-inline input-medium totScore" name="totScore" readonly="">
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-inline input-medium grade" name="grade" readonly="">
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-inline input-medium remark" name="remark" readonly="">
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-inline input-medium position" name="position" readonly="">

          </td>


        </tr>
      </form>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thanks Swati! It's working but if I don't enter the value of CAT first, it doesn't work. What could be the problem?

Comment: It should work then also ...because it doesn't matter which value you input first here in current code we are not using `$(this).val()` instead  `$row.find('.examScore').val()` .

Comment: I observed that any of the input classes that comes first is the one that works when I'm entering the values. Like if '.cat' is first in the function parameter, it adds and display results and '.examScore' doesn't and vise versa.

Comment: I am not seeing any such behaviour ..can you create jsfiddle with that behaviour ?

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/s6uy0ov1 i would not mind collaborating with you @Swati to make sure this issue is resolved as soon as possible. Thanks so much

Comment: why you have `$('#marks').on('input', '.examScore', '.cat',   function() {` ? writing selector like that will always trigger first class which is defined  .Instead please refer my answer closely you will see difference between both.

Comment: Thanks so much @Swati. Works perfectly! I'm pretty much grateful 

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227022/discussion-between-sir-val-and-swati).